# How to efficiently export/import database data with JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, vertica

I have a JAVA application that can use a SQL database from any vendor. Right now we have tested Vertica and PostgreSQL. I want to export all the data from one table in the DB and import it later on in a different instance of the application. The size of the DB is pretty big so there are many rows in there. The export and import process has to be done from inside the java code.

What we've tried so far is:

- Export: we read the whole table (`select * from`) through JDBC and then dump it to an SQL file with all the INSERTS needed.
- Import: The file containing those thousands of INSERTS is executed in the target database through JDBC.

This is not an efficient process. Firstly, the `select * from` part is giving us problems because of the size of it and secondly, executing a lot if inserts one after another gives us problems in Vertica (https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/235201/vjdbc-5065-error-too-many-ros-containers-exist-for-the-following-projections)

What would be a more efficient way of doing this? Are there any tools that can help with the process or there is no "elegant" solution?

Comment: Just as an example, I work with different database types and have a Tool called [SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com/) which is free (as in beer) for personal use. I can connect to all kinds of databases and dump them into files that recreate them from scratch. I have used this mechanism to dump and load databases between engines/systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do the export/import in a single step with batching (for performance) and chunking (to avoid errors and provide a checkpoint where to start off after a failure).

In most cases, databases support `INSERT` queries with many values, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_a (col_a, col_b, ...) VALUES
(val_a, val_b, ...),
(val_a, val_b, ...),
(val_a, val_b, ...),
...
```

The number of rows you generate into a single such `INSERT` statement is then your chunk-size, which might need tuning for the specific target database (big enough to speed things up but small enough to make the chunk not exceed some database limit and create failures).

As already proposed, each of this chunk should then be executed in a transaction and your application should *remember* which chunk it successfully executed last in case some error occurs so it can *continue* at the next run there.

For the chunks itself, you really should use [LIMIT  OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) .

This way, you can repeat any chunk at any time, each chunk by itself is atomic and it should perform much better than with single row statements.

Comment: This turned out to be the most general solution. At the end I created small files with a limited number of rows to be inserted instead of a huge one.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak about PostgreSQL.

The size of the `SELECT` is not a problem if you use server-side cursors by calling `setFetchSize` with a value greater than 0 (perhaps 10000) on the statement.

The `INSERTS` will perform well if

1. you run them all in a single transaction
2. you use a `PreparedStatement` for the `INSERT`

Comment: ¿How can I run them all in a single transaction?. The sql file that is supposed to load all the data into the DB contains a series of INSERT INTO statements one after another. So far I've used the batchUpdate method from JdbcTemplate. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch12s04.html

Comment: You don't use an intermediate SQL script. You just read the data from the source and insert it into the target. If you insist on a file, place `BEGIN;` at the top and `COMMIT;` at the bottom.

Comment: This is also a PostgreSQL specific solution. I need to have a vendor-agnostic process

Comment: JDBC *is* vendor agnostic. Of course the exact behavior will vary for each vendor, but you won't be able to avoid that completely. Pick your stuff together from all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Each insert into Vertica goes into WOS (memory), and periodically data from WOS gets moved to ROS (disk) into a single container. You can only have 1024 ROS containers per projection per node. Doing many thousands of INSERTs at a time is never a good idea for Vertica. The best way to do this is to copy all that data into a file and bulk load the file into Vertica using the `COPY` command.

This will create a single ROS container for the contents of the file. Depending on how many rows you want to copy it will be many times (sometimes even hundreds of times) faster.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/COPY/COPY.htm

https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/ClientJDBC/UsingCOPYLOCALWithJDBC.htm

Comment: The problem is that this will be a vertica specific solution and I want the process to be vendor agnostic

Comment: I can understand that. However, COPY will always be more efficient and more performant than thousands of inserts on Vertica, there's just no way around that. You can try messing with the moveout and mergeout intervals (https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/TupleMover/TuningTheTupleMover.htm). Another thing I've done with Vertica is create a cron job to manually moveout and mergeout a specific table. Create a script with `SELECT DO_TM_TASK('moveout', 'load_table');` and another for mergeout, and set a cronjob. That will help with the ROS container issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Vertica you are using, but in the newest release 9.2 they introduced Reflexive Mergeout (https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/NewFeatures/9.2/9.2.0/DatabaseManagement.htm), which is just a fancy way of saying that mergeouts are more intelligent now. I have used version 9.2 in testing, but not in a production setting with large amounts of data, but it may be worth a try.